# How do I get around the "'" problem in sqlite and c#?

Tags: c#, string, sqlite

I'm working in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express with Sqlite.

I understand that an apostrope (') in my text has problems in a query.  My problem is that I thought I could replace it with \'.  It doesn't seem to be working... Here's a parred down example of my code:

```
string myString = "I can't believe it!";
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into myTable (myid,mytext) values (1,'" + myString.Replace("'","\\'") + "');";
```

The error I get is:
SQLite error:
near "t": syntax error

I've tried a couple other replacements... like the other slash.  And I wrote my string and a replaced version of my string out to the console to make sure it was coming out right.

What stupid error am I making here?

Thanks!

-Adeena

Answer (score 18):

The solution presented by Robert will work (i.e. replacing `'` by `''`).

Alternatively you can use parameters as in:

```
DbCommand   cmd = new DbCommand();
DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
// ...
// more code
// ...
cmd.CommandText = "Insert table (field) values (@param)";
param.ParameterName = "param"
param.DbType = DbType.String;
param.Value  = @"This is a sample value with a single quote like this: '";
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 for using parameters. Robert's solution will work of course, but using parameters will help protect against SQL Injection attacks too.

Comment: So will replacing ' in the input with '' tho.

Answer (score 7):

Using parameters protects against sql injection, and makes the ' problems qo away.

It is also much faster because sqlite can reuse the execution plan of statements when you use parameters. It can't when you don't use parameters. In this example using a parameter makes the bulk insert action approximately 3 times faster.

```
private void TestInsertPerformance() {
  const int limit = 100000;
  using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\testperf.db")) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand()) {
      comm.Connection = conn;
      comm.CommandText = " create table test (n integer) ";
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
      s.Start();
      using (SQLiteTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          comm.CommandText = "insert into test values (" + i.ToString() + ")";
          comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tran.Commit();
      }
      s.Stop();
      MessageBox.Show("time without parm " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

      SQLiteParameter parm = comm.CreateParameter();
      comm.CommandText = "insert into test values (?)";
      comm.Parameters.Add(parm);
      s.Reset();
      s.Start();
      using (SQLiteTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          parm.Value = i;
          comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tran.Commit();
      }
      s.Stop();
      MessageBox.Show("time with parm " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

    }
    conn.Close();
  }
}
```

Sqlite behaves similar to Oracle when it comes to the importance of using parameterised sql statements.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the better answer by far.

Comment: Is it necessary to call conn.Close() when you've got the conn in a "using"? I was told that was redundant.