# How do I count the number of rows returned in my SQLite reader in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm working in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express and with SQLite.

I'm querying my database with something like this:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

cmd.CommandText = "select id from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then I do something like this:

```
if (reader.HasRows == true) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        // I do stuff here
    }
}
```

What I want to do is count the number of rows *before* I do "reader.Read()" since the number returned will affect what I want/need to do.  I know I can add a count within the while statement, but I really need to know the count before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also see [Number of rows in a query result](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Number-of-rows-in-a-query-result-td3570.html) on the SQLite mailing list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The DataReader runs lazily, so it doesn't pick up the entirety of the rowset before beginning.  This leaves you with two choices:

1. Iterate through and count
2. Count in the SQL statement.

Because I'm more of a SQL guy, I'll do the count in the SQL statement:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(id) from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int RowCount = 0;

RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

cmd.CommandText = "select id from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//...
```

Note how I counted *, not id in the beginning. This is because count(id) will ignore id's, while count(*) will only ignore completely null rows.  If you have no null id's, then use count(id) (it's a tad bit faster, depending on your table size).

Update: Changed to ExecuteScalar, and also count(id) based on comments.

Comment: yeah - between your response and Jeremy's this will work.  While "myTable" will be VERY large eventually, the number of rows returned will likely always be small - less than say 10, more often than not it will only be 0-2.  Thanks!

Comment: oh - and "id" will never be null.  If it is, something else is wrong. :)

Comment: How big is "VERY large," and are you sure SQLite is the best thing for that?

Comment: For the moment, as I'm learning while coding, I'm sure SQlite is the best for now.  Will I need to change to some other database solution in the future?  It's likely - but I have so much other things to learn and do, that SQLite is currently meeting my needs.  That table will be a couple thousand entries in the near term, but when my application is done and I'm using it fully, it should have minimum 60,000 and as much as 100,000

Comment: 60,000 - 100,000 isn't much, at all, so you should be peachy keen with that. Best of luck!

Comment: This isn't directly related to the question but I would recommend not using string concatenation to build the sql string, instead use a parametrized query to prevent against possible sql injection.

Comment: @adeena id column can easily be null in select. Even if it's non nullable in schema.
For example in any OUTER JOIN results.

Answer (score 4):

What you request is not feasible -- to quote [Igor Tandetnik](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg38161.html), my emphasis:

> SQLite produces records one by one, on request, every time you call `sqlite3_step`.
>   **It simply doesn't know how many there are going to be**, until on some `sqlite3_step`
>   call it discovers there are no more.

(`sqlite3_step` is the function in SQLite's C API that the C# interface is calling here for each row in the result).

You could rather do a `"SELECT COUNT(*) from myTable where word = '" + word + "';"` first, before your "real" query -- *that* will tell you how many rows you're going to get from the real query.

Answer (score 2):

Do a second query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count(id) from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Your reader will then contain a single row with one column containing the number of rows in the result set. The count will have been performed on the server, so it should be nicely quick.

Comment: Be careful about counting the single field: If it is null, it won't be counted, but will be returned. Make sure a field has a NOT NULL constraint on it before using it in a count.

Comment: Absolutely. Generally, I'd hope an field called "id" is NOT NULL, but you can never be sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only loading an `id` column from the database, would it not be easier to simply load into a `List<string>` and then work from there in memory?

Comment: If you consider the situation where you have a few hundred thousand rows in the table, this would probably not be what you want to do. Better to run another query ahead of time to find the count of the rowset.

Comment: It depends on what the 'I do stuff here' is... depending on the algorithm most/all of the data may end up in memory anyway.

Comment: Also note that in another comment the submitter indicates that typically something like 10 rows is expected from the query, so using a list will probably be faster than two round-trips to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would do

```
select count(1) from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
```

to get the result as fast as possible. In the case where id is an int then it won't make much difference. If it was something a bit bigger like a string type then you'll notice a difference over a large dataset.

Reasoning about it count(1) will include the null rows. But i'm prepared to be corrected if i'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

cmd.CommandText = "select id from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";

SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.HasRows)

     reader.Read();

int total_rows_in_resultset = reader.StepCount;
```

total_rows_in_resultset gives you the number of rows in resultset after processing query

remember that if you wanna use the same reader then close this reader and start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full implementation in a static method.
You should be able to plug this into your class (replace _STR_DB_FILENAME & STR_TABLE_NAME with your database file name and table name).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a count of the number of items in the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetNumberOfItemsInDB()
    {
        // Initialize the count variable to be returned
        int count = 0;            

        // Start connection to db
        using (SqliteConnection db =
            new SqliteConnection("Filename=" + _STR_DB_FILENAME))
        {
            // open connection
            db.Open();

            SqliteCommand queryCommand = new SqliteCommand();
            queryCommand.Connection = db;

            // Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks
            queryCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + _STR_TABLE_NAME;
            // Execute command and convert response to Int
            count = Convert.ToInt32(queryCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            // Close connection
            db.Close();
        }
        // return result(count)
        return count;
    }
```

Note: To improve performance, you can replace '*' in "SELECT COUNT(*)…." with the column name of the primary key in your table for much faster performance on larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

> but I really need to know the count before

Why is that ? this is usually not necessary, if you use adequate in-memory data structures (Dataset, List...). There is probably a way to do what you want that doesn't require to count the rows beforehand.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a version of the "graphmaster" defined here:  http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/matching.html  Basically - if there are 0 or 1 rows, I have a unique answer and no worries.  But if there are 2 or more rows, then I have to do something else fancy to determine which one is the right answer... and it depends on the next node in my "graph".  That's about as best as I can 'splain in a comment! :)

Comment: You could retrieve all rows in a list or DataSet, then check the number of rows and do whatever you need to do on the in-memory data according to the number of rows. Unless the query is likely to fetch  hundreds or thousands of rows, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to count with `select count... from...`

This will make your application slower. However there is an easy way to make your app faster and that way is using parameterized queries.

See here: [How do I get around the "'" problem in sqlite and c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904796/how-do-i-get-around-the-problem-in-sqlite-and-c/926251#926251)

(So besides speed parameterized queries have 2 other advantages too.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
cmd.CommandText = "select id from myTable where word = '" + word + "';";
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
       {
          total_rows_in_resultset++;
       }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information. It is especially important when answering old questions like this one to differentiate your answer from the many other pre-existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a better way to get a row count would be something like this:-

```
 SQLiteDataReader reader = SendReturnSQLCommand(dbConnection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rec_count FROM table WHERE field = 'some_value';");
      if (reader.HasRows) {
         reader.Read();
        int  count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["rec_count"].ToString());

...

    }
```

That way you don't have to iterate over the rows

Comment: Could you please explain what's inside the method SendReturnSQLCommand?