# Insert String in Python SQLite Statement

Tags: python, string, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a string into a SQLite Select statement in python. When I try this  code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE employeeNum = '?'",(empNum,))
```

**I get this error:**

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

**When I try this code:**

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE employeeNum = '",empNum,"'")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

How do I query this string? Sorry I'm new to python. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Do not use string formatting to insert query parameters into the query - this would make sql injections possible, you would have problems with characters that need to be escaped, with data type conversions etc.

Eliminate the quotes around `?` and continue using parameterized query parameters:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DB WHERE employeeNum = ?", (empNum, ))
```

The quotes around `?` made sqlite interpret `?` as a string, not a placeholder.

Also see similar problem:

- [SQLite parameter substitution and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005552/sqlite-parameter-substitution-and-quotes)