# Python: sqlite3 parametrized query gets no results

Tags: python, sqlite, prepared-statement

I try to select entries from a table using parametrized queries. They don't return any results. The code is as follows:

```
var = str.capitalize(var)
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a=(?)', [var])
```

The var is always a three lowercase character string (e.g. 'xxx'), the 'a' column is of type TEXT in the database, and contains three uppercase character strings (e.g. 'XXX').

I tried also the dreadful:

```
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a="%s"' % str.capitalize(var)])
```

because I believed it was a problem with the execute method omitting quotation marks, but it didn't work either. The only thing that got me any results was:

```
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a="XXX"')
```

I am using Python 3.6.0 on Windows 10, someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005552/sqlite-parameter-substitution-and-quotes)  suggested it might be an issue, but their solution didn't work for me either.

Comment: can you share few rows of the table

Comment: 38 GBP 2017-02-24 5.1011
39 GBP 2017-02-27 5.0646
40 GBP 2017-02-28 5.0617

Comment: which column  is a,b,c? and what does `var` contains?

Comment: the columns are (id, a, b, c), var is taken from a form through a POST request and is always like 'gbp', 'usd', 'jpy'.

Comment: i guess you are confused with `capitalize()` and `upper()`

Comment: yes, that was it... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`capitalize` converts only the **first** letter into capital. To convert everything into caps, use `upper()`

Parameter must be passed as tuple/dictionary

Use

```
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a=?', (var.upper(),))
```

Or

```
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a=:var', {"var":var.upper()})
```

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `upper` to convert it to all capitalize, try this:

```
var = var.upper()
selected  =  db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a=?', (var,))
```

this one will work also:

```
var = var.upper()
selected = db.execute('select a, b, c from table1 where a="%s"'%var]
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem... Thank you!

Comment: Cool, glad it helps :)