# 'No such column' in sqlite when parsing string as a parameter

Tags: python, sqlite

For better understanding: This is a program to manage the inventory of a green house, so its about plants treated as products.
I'm getting a weird error when trying to update a value in my sqlite data base. I'm using a function I called *sqUpdateOne* that updates a value in my db according to the given parameters. Here it is:

```
# Sqlite database value updater
def sqUpdateOne(table, column, newValue, refColumn, refValue):
    try:
        with conn:
            c.execute(f'''UPDATE {table} SET "{column}" = {newValue} WHERE {refColumn} = {refValue}''')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'No se pudo actualizar la tabla {table} - {e}')
```

In this case "sqUpdateOne" is called by this function:

```
def modifValue(column, id, prevValue, modValue):
if modValue != prevValue:
    idCol = 'id'
    invCol = 'inventario'
    sqUpdateOne(invCol, column, modValue, idCol, id)
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Also worth to note: when "modValue" (which later is "newValue" in "sqUpdateOne") is an integer or float it all works fine.
As an example: when i do:

```
sqUpdateOne('inventory','product','newPlant",'idColumn',001)
```

So this shoud update the column "product" in the table "inventory", specifically the value where "idColumn" is 001, and set that value to "newPlant" (right??)
Well... if I do this it gives me an error like

> No such column: "newPlant"

So.. in general: The error im geting is when I give it a **string** in the "newValue" parameter, I dont know why but it takes that value as the "column" value, and gives me the "no such column" error.

**sqUpdateOne is used in many other situatuions in this program and I dont have any problems when the value I give to the "newValue" parameter is an integer or float**

Comment: You're getting error because string values needs quotes around them in a sql query. Better to use a parameterised query, which will protect against SQL injection attacks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005552/sqlite-parameter-substitution-and-quotes

Comment: @jignatius thanks a lot, that solved it and i'll look into parameterized query's right now (I may have to re-write a lot of code haha). One more question: the quotes around the parameter affect the fact that I may try to put an *integer* there? in the case I try to do this in a column defined as integer

Comment: Try this: `c.execute(f'''UPDATE {table} SET "{column}" = ? WHERE {refColumn} = ?''', (newValue, refValue))` This is a parameterised query, which should work for different types of values.

Comment: @jignatius Nice! thanks a lot, that was really helpfull