# Best serverless database to be used for large static indexed data?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sqlite

What is the best serverless database to use with static data to be queried in a good performance, the data will have many indexes?

I have some data that will be queried,I don't need any type of transactions or alterations on it, the data is 5.0 GB, i need it to be deployed with some app, i need 40 indexes on my columns, what is the best technoology to use, i cann't use SQL CE because of data size limitation, my suggestions are sqlite and Firebird, are there other options, what is the best, and why?

**NOTE** : 
most of indexes are on int columns and others on small string columns to be compared using (=) operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using SQLite with Transactions. Up to now I never experienced any performance issues with it, running a 1 GB database file.

Perhaps this link will help:
[SO on using SQLite with large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033309/sqlite-for-large-data-sets)

SQLite has some problems with concurrency, but if you do not have lots of users, then it will be a good choice:

[SQLite official When to use](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

and there are some restrictions, which almost never happen in productive use (e.g. 2 GB Blobs)
[SQlite offical Limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)