# Is there any way to use CSV as Database in C language?

Tags: sql, c, csv

I want to use csv as a database in C language to execute some sql commands for filtration. Just like CSV-jdbc api is there in Java. Is there any way to do this???

Comment: Why do you want that? Why can't you parse your CSV then fill a database e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) ?

Comment: I dont want to use database at all.

Comment: Then why speak of SQL? SQL is for databases!

Comment: Actually, i dont want to install external database. 
I want something like csv-jdbc api provided in Java.

Comment: But [SQLITE](http://sqlite.org/) is not an *external* database!

Comment: And if you want exactly csv-jdbc (which I never heard about) just code your application in Java.

Comment: Actually I want to make a utility in C and then use it in Java as dll. Is this possible if i use sqlite.

Comment: csv-jdbc is not much efficient.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite would fit perfectly in your case ! You don't want an external database and you want to use it easily in C. So SQLite is the thing that you need !

Here is the doc : http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html
And the list of functions : http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html

Comment: Is this efficient for huge data like more than 1 GB file.

Comment: Yes it is. See Sqlite's [limits](http://sqlite.org/limits.html). It is supposed to be able to handle a 100 terabyte database.

Comment: SQLite will handle [big] file just fine; make sure to import the records in a transaction so that it doesn't spend a lot of time creating indexes until everything is imported.    from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033309/sqlite-for-large-data-sets

Comment: can u provide a little snapshot of code. That will be helpful.