# Optimisation techniques for sqlite database

Tags: sql, optimization, sqlite

I'm creating Android application that contains a large amount of data. It takes lot of time to access the data. What are optimization technique that I can use ? Are there any optimized queries?

Comment: you are going to have to ask something a bit more specific

Answer (score 1):

This page will give you a lot of good tips on how to optimize SQLite things:

http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html

Keep in mind that some stuff SQLite will optimize for you as well when it runs a query:

http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

Comment: Please don't add links as answers, rather put a bit of key info from the page and reference. Often these links change...

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized queries to reduce the amount of queries that needs to be parsed, see: [How do I get around the "'" problem in sqlite and c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904796/how-do-i-get-around-the-problem-in-sqlite-and-c/926251#926251)

Comment: i cannot use parameterized queries in sqlite for android database,is there anyother options for Query optimisarion

Comment: Are you sure? I don't know Android. I assumed there is only one kind of Sqlite.

Answer (score -1):

You can use parametrized statements in Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score -2):

SQLite does not support dates natively (SQLite uses strings to store dates). If you are using an index to access dates - you'll get slow query times (not to mention inaccurate or wrong results..)

If you really need to sort through dates then I'd suggest you create separate columns for the various date elements that you want to index (like years, months, and days). Define these columns as integers and add INDEX statements to index their contents.

Comment: Liron, you should add details of your utility to your user profile.