# How do I use a parameterized query in LuaSQLite 3?

Tags: sql, lua, coronasdk

How do you use parameterized query in LuaSQLite 3?

I've tried understanding the documentations at:

http://luasqlite.luaforge.net/lsqlite3.html#methods for prepared statements

and looked at the example here:

[How to quote values for LuaSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224806/how-to-quote-values-for-luasql)

but I can't get this to work:

```
getTable = function( _key)
    local path = system.pathForFile("database.db", system.ResourceDirectory)
    local dc = sqlite3.open( path )

    local stmt = dc:prepare[[ SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Key = :Key ]]
    local sql = stmt:bind({key=_weaponType})
    return dc:nrows(sql)
end
```

I get the error:

```
attempt to index 'stmt' (a nil value)
```

on the line:

```
local sql = stmt:bind({key=_weaponType})
```

P.S.  I'm currently developing a game in Corona SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `attempt to index 'stmt' (a nil value)` error means `dc:prepare` didn't return anything.

I assume it is actually returning `nil,errormsg`: check what the error is; your statement is probably ill-formed.

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible to have more 1 return value in LUA!  Thank you, this helped me solve my issue.

Comment: you just made a Lua Uppercase Accident: its just lua (you don't have  PYTHON) :)

Answer (score 0):

When stmt is a null value is because the prepare instruction failed. Ensure that all the fields exist and the query is valid