# Parameterized query in LuaSQL

Tags: lua, luasql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quote values for LuaSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224806/how-to-quote-values-for-luasql)

Does LuaSQL offer parameterized queries? I've poked through the source and it seems like a big "no".