# What quirks should I look out for when developing for the Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: android, testing, android-hardware

I recently released a game on the Android market. It seems to be working fine for most people, but everyone using a Samsung Galaxy S is reporting the same problem: The graphics for the game are not being drawn on screen (though they appear to be present, sound effects are still generated). The game uses a SurfaceView to draw the various elements from PNG graphics, and everything is scaled so that it will work on any resolution. I don't have a Galaxy S, so debugging is quite hard, can anyone who's had experience developing on a Galaxy S let me know if they found any particular quirks with the device?

Comment: OK, today I got a Samsung Galaxy S! The problem was the `Canvas` I was drawing onto being measured by my app before it had been initialized! All sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try loading the files in a loading screen to memory first and only then play the game.

Comment: Perform the loading of all the items you are goid to display and use for example: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(id) and SoundPool.Load() on all the files you are going to be needing as soon as the game starts. and only then beging the game using the handles you have just recived from all the loading methods you called.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000 has very slow internal sd card. It is probably due to errors in a file system. Make sure your application does I/O operations on internal sd card only when absoultely neccessary.

Check here for details:

[SQLite is extremely slow in Samsung Galaxy GT-I9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501451/sqlite-is-extremely-slow-in-samsung-galaxy-gt-i9000)

Comment: It could be a problem with loading the image files from internal storage I guess, but wouldn't that throw some kind of exception if there was a file IO problem?